# How to understand Expressions?

Tags: c

I have done some experiments using expressions. When I am working with some code, I found this unusual thing.

- **First trial**

```
    int i = 3;
    int j = 5;
    j >= i;

    printf("Output1 = %d\n", i);
    printf("Output2 = %d", j);
```

when I compiled this code I got **error** messge.

- **Second trial**

```
    int i = 3;
    int j >= i;

    printf("Output1 = %d\n", i);
    printf("Output2 = %d", j);

    return 0;
```

This also give me an **error** message.

- **Third trial**

```
    int i = 3;
    int j = 5 >= i;

    printf("Output1 = %d\n", i);
    printf("Output2 = %d", j);
```

1) If `i <= 5` output will be

```
Output1 = 3                                                                                         
Output2 = 1
```

2) If `i > 5` output will be

```
Output1 = 3                                                                                         
Output2 = 0
```

Why my first trial and second trials give errors and third one compiled unharmly?

I need some explanation.

Comment: In the first trial, the statement `j >= i;` has no effect on the computation so it is ignored by the compiler.  Your compiler settings might convert that warning into an error, which is a Good Thing™.  The second trial is an outright syntax error.  You can't use a comparison in place of an initializer.  The third trial is fine and gives the expected results.  The value of a comparison such as `5 >= i` is either 0 if the comparison is false or 1 if the comparison is true.

Comment: but in third one also have comparision in initializer but it didn't give an syntax error or compile error

Comment: In the third one, you have `int j = …something…` which is a valid initializer (and the `…something…` is a valid comparison). Initializers start with an `=` symbol.  In the second, you have `int j >= i;` — this does not start with `=` and hence is invalid.  Note that trying `int j == i;` would also be invalid; the symbol is `==` and not `=`.

Comment: See C11 [§6.7.9 Initialization](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9) and [§6.7 Declarations](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7) for the syntax of intializers.

Comment: In general, when you're reporting that the compiler gives an error message, you should include the error message in the text of the question.  Minimize the file name — if the compiler says `/home/whoever/projects/project13/file1.c`, you can reduce that to just `file1.c` so that the error message is readble.

Comment: Then it means comparition which is in initializer is true it outputs 1. If false it output 0.

Comment: Yes, the comparison in the initializer generates either 1 (true) or 0 (false) — that is the value assigned to `j`, as your tests showed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

In the first trial, the statement `j >= i;` has no effect on the computation so it is ignored by the compiler. Your compiler settings might convert that warning into an error, which is a Good Thing™.

The second trial is an outright syntax error. You can't use a comparison in place of an initializer.

The third trial is fine and gives the expected results. The value of a comparison such as `5 >= i` is either 0 if the comparison is false or 1 if the comparison is true.

> But in the third one, there is also a comparison in the initializer but it didn't give an syntax error or compile error

In the third one, you have:

```
int j = …something…;
```

which is a valid initializer (because the …something… is a valid comparison). Initializers start with an `=` symbol. In the second, you have `nt j >= i;` — this does not start with `=` and hence is invalid. Note that trying `int j == i;` would also be invalid; the symbol is `==` and not `=`.

See C11 [§6.7.9 Initialization](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9) and [§6.7 Declarations](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7) for the syntax of intializers.

> Then it means comparison which is in initializer is true it outputs 1. If false it output 0.

Yes, the comparison in the initializer generates either 1 (true) or 0 (false) — that is the value assigned to `j`, as your tests showed.